# High latency/ping to local gateway WHILE STREAMING [wireless]

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, gateway, latency, local

Recently I've become fed up with my wireless internet and want to identify the problem. I don't have a patch cord yet to test a direct connection but so far every computer I've tested has reported high latency while trying to ping the wireless gateway (192.168.0.1).

Here is a ping test result on the computer I'm at now: http://pastebin.com/JQj2dPy6

Keep in mind my desktop computer is currently streaming a 1080p live stream from Twitch. Is this the sole reason my gateway is taking so long to respond? My connection to the WAN is set at 30Mbs download and 5Mbs upload, so why would a 1080p stream (estimating 10Mbs download) slow down my local network?

Here is a picture from inSSIDer 2.1 showing the wireless networks in my area. Everyone is stacked on channel 6 with one network on channel 11 while MINE is alone on channel 1.

[image: 1]

Any ideas or help is appreciated!

Comment: If you stop streaming, do your ping times drop dramatically? Get onto 5GHz if you want to stream.

Comment: I don't think my router supports multi-band use, but I've also posted this question at superuser's sister site serverfault.com (http://serverfault.com/questions/480041/high-latency-ping-to-local-gateway-while-streaming-wireless). One guy responded saying pinging a gateway is not indicative of effective throughput and therefore shouldn't be used in diagnosing network problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at those pings suggests to me a noisy environment, ie you are hitting the useable limit on your wifi.  Maybe your WIFI router needs attention (replacement/new firmware ?)

Answer (score 1):

The guy is right. Ping is only a connectivity tool, not a performance test. Basically it's just a machine way of saying "Hello, are you awake".

Network devices give ICMP a very low priority. It's one way to prevent Ping of Death. Ping is handled by the router's CPU, which is also handling NAT of your traffic. What those results are telling is just that the CPU is too busy NATting and doing other router-y things to respond to ping immediately.

For performance measurement you need to use a tool that's intended for that, for example [iperf](https://iperf.fr/). You run the stream on one system. Then start iperf server on another system, and run iperf client on a third one. Then stop the stream and do the iperf test again. That way you can see how much the stream affects the actual network performance.